# How can I use Core Graphics to draw a circle at my touch location?

Tags: ios, xcode, touch, cgcontext

New programmer here. I am having issues trying to use Core Graphics to draw a stroked arc around my touch location. I have the method to draw the circle working fine, and I have tested and am registering touches when I tap the screen, but when I try to call the method to draw the circle when I tap, I get the error "CGContextBlahBlah: invalid context 0x0"

I *think* that this is because I'm not calling the method in drawRect:().

So how am I able to call this method on a touch? Furthermore, how can I use the "CGPoint locationOfTouch" as a parameter in my draw method?

Here are the code chunks I am working with.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationOfTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self drawTouchCircle:(locationOfTouch)];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


-(void)drawTouchCircle:(CGPoint)locationOfTouch
{
    CGContextRef ctx= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,5);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx,0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx,locationOfTouch.x,locationOfTouch.y,30,0.0,M_PI*2,YES);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: As Rob says, your suspicion is correct — in iOS all drawing is pull rather than push.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're right. The issue is that, rather than calling `drawTouchCircle` yourself, you should implement a `drawRect` method that calls it for you, and thus your `touches` method only needs to call `setNeedsDisplay`, and `drawRect` will take care of the rest. You might, therefore, want to save the touch location in a class property, and then retrieve that in your `drawRect`:

```
@interface View ()
@property (nonatomic) BOOL touched;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint locationOfTouch;
@end

@implementation View

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    self.touched = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    self.locationOfTouch = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawTouchCircle:(CGPoint)locationOfTouch
{
    CGContextRef ctx= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect bounds = [self bounds];

    CGPoint center;
    center.x = bounds.origin.x + bounds.size.width / 2.0;
    center.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height / 2.0;
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,5);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx,0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0);
    CGContextAddArc(ctx,locationOfTouch.x,locationOfTouch.y,30,0.0,M_PI*2,YES);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.touched)
        [self drawTouchCircle:self.locationOfTouch];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This looks to be heading in the right direction for me, so thank you for that. Upon adding the property portion in the header file and synthesize in the m file I was presented with a warning saying that a "Local declaration of "locationOfTouch" hides instance variable. Does this mean I need to use another declaration other than synthesize? Apologies if the answer is obvious, I am still trying to grasp the main ideas.

Comment: @BendE As an aside, you also said that you added this property to your .h file. The emerging best practice is to _not_ have these sorts of private properties declared in your .h file, but rather define it in a "private class extension" in your .m file, like I did above. That way, you don't expose other classes to properties that are private implementation details for your `UIView` subclass. Now, if you need other classes to have access to it, then certainly define it in your .h file. But if not, keep it out of there, and put it in your .m's private class extension.

Comment: Hmm, it seems my issue was in the draw method, as I was using `locationOfTouch.x` instead of `self.locationOfTouch.x` as a parameter. Though I am still not getting anything when I touch. Also, when i remove the `@synthesize` I get another warning stating that _touched requires method setTouched to be defined_

Comment: Thank you for the responses! It seems to be working correctly now.