# Resize image drawn with CoreGraphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I've followed question [How can I use Core Graphics to draw a circle at my touch location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905616/how-can-i-use-core-graphics-to-draw-a-circle-at-my-touch-location) and now I have circles in my touch position.

Now I'd like to have a pinch gesture to resize view with circles (like zooming photos in Photo.app) Is it possible to achieve this behavior with CoreGraphics objects?

Here is my circle drawing code:

```
CGContextRef ctx= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,5);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx,0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0);
CGContextAddArc(ctx,20,40,30,0.0,M_PI*2,YES);
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all, you need to setup your views's hierarchy (programatically or via Interface Builder)..

For example:

```
UIViewController
  UIView 
    UISrollView
      UIView
        UIImageView
```

[image]

2) Setup autolayout. (http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/)

3) Draw your circle. This example is for IB setup approach

```
- (UIImage *)drawCircle {
  CGContextRef ctx= UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
  CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx,5);
  CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx,0.8,0.8,0.8,1.0);
  CGContextAddArc(ctx,20,40,30,0.0,M_PI*2,YES);
  CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

  return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageView.image = [self drawCircle];
}
```

4) Setup Pinch Gestures:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html

[Pinch To Zoom Effect on UIImageView inside scrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877807/pinch-to-zoom-effect-on-uiimageview-inside-scrollview)